# NoClassDefFoundError when running java program in linux/ubuntu

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm unable to run my java program in linux/ubuntu.
I've been working on this problem for a whole day now and can't seem to find any solution. 
I wrote a small java program using Eclipse on my Windows 7 machine and it works just fine. Here's my code:

```
//start of java program jsonReader
package jsonReader;
//imports needed to run program
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
```

In order for the import org.codehause.jackson.. to work, I had to manually include in my project this jar file: jackson-all-1.9.11.jar

```
    //class jsonReader
    public class jsonReader {
    //start of main 
            public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

The rest of this is my program which works just fine.

The next step to my project is to run it on Ubuntu - command line. I did an export on Eclipses:
        File -> Export -> General -> Archive File -> and created a Zip File.

This zip file was transferred to my linux/ubuntu enviornment. From there, I unzipped the file. This is the directory structure:

in home directory I have:

```
/jsonReader --> has the following directories in it:
               -/bin/jsonReader/jsonReader.class
               -/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar
               -/src/jsonReader/jsonReader.java
               -.classpath (file); and a few other files.
```

In /jsonReader/src/jsonReader I run this command: javac jsonReader.java --> I get this error:

```
    jsonReader.java:6: package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
    ^
    jsonReader.java:7: package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
    import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
    ^
```

Then I run this command:

```
javac -classpath /jsonReader/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar jsonReader.java
```

I get no errors. This command creates a jsonReader.class file in the /src/jsonReader directory. I try to run the file using this command:

```
java jsonReader
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsonReader (wrong name: jsonReader/jsonReader)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: jsonReader. Program will exit.
```

This is the entire error message that I'm getting, when running this on the command line.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to run the program like so

```
java -cp /jsonReader/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar jsonReader.jsonReader
```

Assuming the jackson jar is in `/jsonReader/lib`.

You need to use the fully qualified class name of the class whose `main` method you want to run.

---

An example so it can work.

Create the following structure

```
/project
    /src
        /jsonReaderTemp
            /jsonReader.java
    /bin 
        /jsonReaderTemp
            /jsonReader.class
    /lib
        /jackson-all-1.9.11.jar
```

You can either create it manually or use the command line to do it, up to you.

With the above, `cd` to `project` and run

```
java -cp lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar;bin jsonReaderTemp.jsonReader
```

Note the `;` as a separator for classpath directories.

---

Note that java convention states that class names should start with an uppercase character, so `JsonReader` and package names should be all lowercase, separating words with `.` if you need to (but there shouldn't be words like that).

Comment: Hello, I tried running that command, but it still didn't work. I ran it from /jsonReader/src/jsonReader (there is a .class file there) And I also ran it from /jsonReader/src directory. Both gave me the same error .. NoClassDefFound.

Comment: @user2809181 If `jsonReader.class` is in `src/jsonReader`, ie. `src/jsonReader/jsonReader.class`, you should run it from `src`.

Comment: @user2809181 I might have misunderstood your directory structure. Please lay it out in an edit to your question.

Comment: @user2809181 You have two options: 1) Run it from wherever you want and specify the full path to the `bin` folder in your classpath. 2) Run it from `bin`, the current directory should automatically be added to the classpath.

Comment: I tried both options. Here is my command:  java -cp /jsonReader/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar jsonReader/bin/jsonReader/jsonReader.jsonReader --> and still get the same error unfortunantly.

Comment: @user2809181 Nono, `cd` to the bin directory and run the command in my answer.

Comment: @user2809181 Are you sure its the same error? Try renaming your class so it doesn't match the package name. It's kind of confusing right now :(. From `bin`, change the classpath to `-cp lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar` to add the jackson jar.

Comment: My apologies for making this so confusing. Here's what I did now. I changed the package name from jsonReader to jsonReaderTemp. (It wouldn't allow me to change the classname). I then used javac and specified the classpath, and it worked fine. Now, I'm running java -cp /jsonReader/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar jsonReader.jsonReader. And this is the error I get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsonReaderTemp/jsonReader Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jsonReaderTemp.jsonReader .. Even I"m getting so confused with all this.

Comment: I also, tried another thing. I created a generic HellowWorld.java, which works fine, until I add "package HelloWorld;" in the beginning of the file. I then start getting the same errors.

Comment: @user I've added a directory structure that should work if you follow it. Obviously you can call your folders and files according to what you have, but be consistent in your changes.

Comment: @user2809181 Oops, remove the leading `/` from the classpath entries. I've edited it to correct that.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Actually my current directory structure is the same as the one you suggested, but when I ran my java command: java -cp /jsonReader/lib/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar jsonReader.jsonReader I didn't include ":bin" as part of the class path. So, as you suggested, I ran my command from the project folder and included ":bin". Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @User You are welcome. Consider accepting the answer  (check the checkmark) if it covered everything.